# Quartz server's problems locked my deploy last night

Tags: deployment, quartz-scheduler, xsd-validation, http-status-code-503

Last night I was trying to deploy my web application on Tomcat7, but it repeatedly failed because quartz server was unreachable.

Context was not able to load because it was not able to download http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd

Any suggestion? I was thinking about downloading the file a loading it from our domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this happened only once. There was no need to move xsd on our domain.
It was a strange issue.